# how Access to a span tag without class name

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I have this codes in my SimpleHtmlDom Project 
how can I access this span Tags without Class Name?

```
<div class="somename">
<span>This text i need </span>
<span>This text i need too </span>
</div>
```

how can I echo that span tags?
I already tried this:

```
$html->find(".somename",0)->innertext;
```

Comment: How about: `$html->find(".somename span",0)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using `simple_html_dom.php`. If that is the case then:

`$html->find("span",0)->innertext;`

should give you the first span

`$html->find("span",1)->innertext;`

should give you the second span

`$html->find("span")->innertext;`

should give you all spans in an array

If you are trying to retrieve the content of the span you should use `plaintext` not `innertext`

If you want it to specifically search for spans in a div with a class somename you can do it like this:

`$html->find("div[class=somename] span")->innertext;`

Reference: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: this solution does not work either because this code just finds parent spans and in my case spans are children of a div!

Comment: @shevoac i fixed the answer. See the last example I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath to get those `span` tags.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($yourHtmlContents);
$result = $xml->xpath('//span');

$firstSpan = (string) $result[0];
$secondSpan = (string) $result[1];
```

Comment: actually, my code does not as simple as this I have many div and span this is not work for me.

Comment: how I should fill $yourHtmlContents ? is it a "simplehtldom" object? or just a regular domain string ??